# how can i test flash applications?

Tags: flash, testing

flashwatir appears to be dead.

is there anyway I can interact with objects in flash apps ? like clicking button and such from a gui-less linux server ?

like

```
flashapp.button.click("flash button")
puts flashapp.button.text # returns the text label of flash button
```

Answer (score 3):

We've been using [RiaTest](http://www.riatest.com/) , and [FlexMonkey](http://code.google.com/p/flexmonkey/)

(with various levels of success... we always got into some troubles in very specific cases).

However, for Flex like for any kind of GUI, I would suggest you try designing your code so that you can use pure flexunit tests to check most of your logic, before you go into "functionnal" testing in the browser.

Most of the time, I don't want to check that clicking on a button calls a function ; what I want is to test that the function works.

Hoping this helps.

Comment: i need a solution that runs on linux server. will any of those work on a gui-less environment.

Comment: FlexUnit as a way to launch FlexUnit test with ant : http://www.blackpepper.co.uk/black-pepper-blog/Flex-unit-testing-and-continuous-integration.html . And you might use something like xvfb to launch firefox on the server ... http://semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/xvfb-firefox.html ... good luck in all cases !

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org) with the [Flash-Selenium extension](http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/) - disclaimer, I haven't personally used this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Sikuli. This is a image comparison tool, where you could pre-capture the button's image and in your test script say click the image. (Position of image in app doesn't matter)

If the app is a built using flex, you could take a look at Adobe Genie. This does not require any rebuild of the flex app. And it uses object recognition.

Both of these will work in Linux.